# How to get title from url with react-native-link-preview

Tags: javascript, react-native

I found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-link-preview) module that I want to use to get title from url. 
Problem is that I don't know how to access the data that this module provides me.

Basically I want to get title from given url and print it in view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the title by using the getPreview method of this module.
For example if you want to get the title of a youtube video use below code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import LinkPreview from 'react-native-link-preview';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     title : "sample title"
   }
  }

  getTitle() {
   LinkPreview.getPreview('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqz-KE-bpKQ')
    .then(data => this.setState({title: data.title}));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getTitle();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Title is : {this.state.title}</Text>
      </View>
   );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps !